# spark - avoid stackoverflow error for lengthy schema

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark code that defines a schema with 950+ columns. It is something like below

```
 val cust_schema = new StructType()
    .add(StructField("COL_1",DecimalType(16,0)))
    .add(StructField("COL_2",StringType))
    .add(StructField("COL_3",DecimalType(6,0)))
    .add(StructField("COL_4",StringType))
    .add(StructField("COL_5",StringType))
    .add(StructField("COL_6",DecimalType(4,0)))
    . . . . 
    . . . . 

    .add(StructField("COL_950",DecimalType(4,0)))
    .add(StructField("COL_951",DecimalType(4,0)))
    .add(StructField("COL_952",StringType))
```

I get error when I compile this

```
Error:scalac: Error: org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.ServerException
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Contexts$Context.bufferErrors(Contexts.scala:332)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Contexts$Context.reportErrors(Contexts.scala:333)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:672)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5478)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedSelectOrSuperCall$1(Typers.scala:4812)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5344)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5478)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedSelectOrSuperCall$1(Typers.scala:4812)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5344)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5478)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedSelectOrSuperCall$1(Typers.scala:4812)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5344)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5478)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedSelectOrSuperCall$1(Typers.scala:4812)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5344)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5478)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedSelectOrSuperCall$1(Typers.scala:4812)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5344)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5478)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedSelectOrSuperCall$1(Typers.scala:4812)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5344)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5478)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedSelectOrSuperCall$1(Typers.scala:4812)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5344)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5478)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedSelectOrSuperCall$1(Typers.scala:4812)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5344)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5478)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedSelectOrSuperCall$1(Typers.scala:4812)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5344)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5478)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedSelectOrSuperCall$1(Typers.scala:4812)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5344)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5478)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedSelectOrSuperCall$1(Typers.scala:4812)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5344)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5478)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedSelectOrSuperCall$1(Typers.scala:4812)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5344)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5478)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedSelectOrSuperCall$1(Typers.scala:4812)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5344)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5478)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedSelectOrSuperCall$1(Typers.scala:4812)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5344)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$99.apply(Typers.scala:4525)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:680)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.normalTypedApply$1(Typers.scala:4524)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedApply$1(Typers.scala:4580)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5343)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5360)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.runTyper$1(Typers.scala:5396)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedInternal(Typers.scala:5423)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.body$2(Typers.scala:5370)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5374)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5472)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedQualifier(Typers.scala:5478)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedSelectOrSuperCall$1(Typers.scala:4812)

at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedInAnyMode$1(Typers.scala:5344)

. . . . 
. . . . .
```

When I reduce the number of columns to 500+, the code compiles.. but it is not always consistent. The compiler throws error sometimes even for <500 columns.
Has anyone encountered such issues and have a fix for this?.

Comment: I have imported CSV files with over 2000 columns and modified their schema. I never had this issue. Although I haven't added schemas as you are doing it. Are you sure it is a Spark issue? I see that you got the `ServerException`. Please see this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41442026/how-to-get-rid-of-scalac-serverexception-with-intellij-idea)

Comment: @Nikhil - let me try that too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like scala compiler issue. 
You can try to use Seq base constructor instead of chain calls

```
val cust_schema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("COL_1",DecimalType(16,0)),
  StructField("COL_2",DecimalType(16,0)),
  ...
  StructField("COL_952",DecimalType(16,0))
))
```

Comment: Fixed example code. I added ")" to close the StructField "(".  It is compiled locally:
    
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

    object A {
    val seq = Seq(
    StructField("COL_1",DecimalType(16,0)),
StructField("COL_1",DecimalType(16,0))
)
val cust_schema = StructType(seq)
}

Comment: sorry I meant.. tried the pattern that you mentioned here.. and got the same error as in the original post..

Comment: I increased the heap as mentioned in some other link and with ````StrucType(Seq(...)))```` it works now.. thank you so much