# Cannot get Play Framework starting project to work

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I checked out a starter project for Play Framework from https://playframework.com/download#starters on Windows and I have installed sbt and Play via IntelliJ. When I run sbt console and then compile or run, I get this output. What should I do to make it work?

> D:\Projekty\play-scala-starter-example>.\sbt-dist\bin\sbt.bat Java
>   HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option
>   MaxPermSize=256m; sup port was removed in 8.0 [info] Loading project
>   definition from D:\Projekty\play-scala-starter-example\pr oject [info]
>   Set current project to play-scala-starter-example (in build
>   file:/D:/Proj ekty/play-scala-starter-example/)
>   [play-scala-starter-example] $ run
>
> --- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---
>
> java.lang.VerifyError: Uninitialized object exists on backward branch
>   209 Exception Details:   Location:
>       scala/collection/immutable/HashMap$HashTrieMap.split()Lscala/collection/immu
>   table/Seq; @249: goto   Reason:
>       Error exists in the bytecode   Bytecode:
>       0x0000000: 2ab6 005b 04a0 001e b200 b3b2 00b8 04bd
>       0x0000010: 0002 5903 2a53 c000 bab6 00be b600 c2c0
>       0x0000020: 00c4 b02a b600 31b8 003b 3c1b 04a4 015e
>       0x0000030: 1b05 6c3d 2a1b 056c 2ab6 0031 b700 c63e
>       0x0000040: 2ab6 0031 021d 787e 3604 2ab6 0031 0210
>       0x0000050: 201d 647c 7e36 05bb 0014 59b2 00b8 2ab6
>       0x0000060: 0033 c000 bab6 00ca b700 cd1c b600 d13a
>       0x0000070: 0619 06c6 001a 1906 b600 d5c0 0081 3a07
>       0x0000080: 1906 b600 d8c0 0081 3a08 a700 0dbb 00da
>       0x0000090: 5919 06b7 00dd bf19 073a 0919 083a 0abb
>       0x00000a0: 0002 5915 0419 09bb 0014 59b2 00b8 1909
>       0x00000b0: c000 bab6 00ca b700 cd03 b800 e33a 0e3a
>       0x00000c0: 0d03 190d b900 e701 0019 0e3a 1136 1036
>       0x00000d0: 0f15 0f15 109f 0027 150f 0460 1510 190d
>       0x00000e0: 150f b900 ea02 00c0 0005 3a17 1911 1917
>       0x00000f0: b800 ee3a 1136 1036 0fa7 ffd8 1911 b800
>       0x0000100: f2b7 0060 3a0b bb00 0259 1505 190a bb00
>       0x0000110: 1459 b200 b819 0ac0 00ba b600 cab7 00cd
>       0x0000120: 03b8 00e3 3a13 3a12 0319 12b9 00e7 0100
>       0x0000130: 1913 3a16 3615 3614 1514 1515 9f00 2715
>       0x0000140: 1404 6015 1519 1215 14b9 00ea 0200 c000
>       0x0000150: 053a 1819 1619 18b8 00f5 3a16 3615 3614
>       0x0000160: a7ff d819 16b8 00f2 b700 603a 0cb2 00fa
>       0x0000170: b200 b805 bd00 0259 0319 0b53 5904 190c
>       0x0000180: 53c0 00ba b600 beb6 00fd b02a b600 3303
>       0x0000190: 32b6 00ff b0   Stackmap Table:
>       same_frame(@35)
>       full_frame(@141,{Object[#2],Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Object[#
>   109]},{})
>       append_frame(@151,Object[#129],Object[#129])
>       full_frame(@209,{Object[#2],Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Object[#
>   109],Object[#129],Object[#129],Object[#129],Object[#129],Top,Top,Object[#20],Obj
>   ect[#55],Integer,Integer,Object[#107]},{Uninitialized[#159],Uninitialized[#159],
>   Integer,Object[#129]})
>       full_frame(@252,{Object[#2],Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Object[#
>   109],Object[#129],Object[#129],Object[#129],Object[#129],Top,Top,Object[#20],Obj
>   ect[#55],Integer,Integer,Object[#107]},{Uninitialized[#159],Uninitialized[#159],
>   Integer,Object[#129]})
>       full_frame(@312,{Object[#2],Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Object[#
>   109],Object[#129],Object[#129],Object[#129],Object[#129],Object[#2],Top,Object[#
>   20],Object[#55],Integer,Integer,Object[#107],Object[#20],Object[#55],Integer,Int
>   eger,Object[#107]},{Uninitialized[#262],Uninitialized[#262],Integer,Object[#129]
>   })
>       full_frame(@355,{Object[#2],Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Object[#
>   109],Object[#129],Object[#129],Object[#129],Object[#129],Object[#2],Top,Object[#
>   20],Object[#55],Integer,Integer,Object[#107],Object[#20],Object[#55],Integer,Int
>   eger,Object[#107]},{Uninitialized[#262],Uninitialized[#262],Integer,Object[#129]
>   })
>       full_frame(@395,{Object[#2],Integer},{})
>
> ```
>     at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$.scala$collection$immutable$HashMa
> ```
>
> p$$makeHashTrieMap(HashMap.scala:182)
>           at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashMap1.updated0(HashMap.scala:21
>   7)
>           at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap.updated(HashMap.scala:59)
>           at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map4.updated(Map.scala:201)
>           at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map4.$plus(Map.scala:202)
>           at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map4.$plus(Map.scala:180)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.MapBuilder.$plus$eq(MapBuilder.scala:29)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.MapBuilder.$plus$eq(MapBuilder.scala:25)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$anonfun$toMap$1(TraversableOnce.sca
>   la:317)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$Lambda$14/1024989843.apply(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toMap(TraversableOnce.scala:316)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toMap$(TraversableOnce.scala:314)
>           at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.toMap(Traversable.scala:104)
>           at scala.concurrent.duration.Duration$.(Duration.scala:88)
>           at scala.concurrent.duration.Duration$.(Duration.scala)
>           at akka.util.Helpers$ConfigOps$.getDuration$extension(Helpers.scala:137)
>
> ```
>     at akka.util.Helpers$ConfigOps$.getMillisDuration$extension(Helpers.scal
> ```
>
> a:132)
>           at akka.actor.ActorSystem$Settings.(ActorSystem.scala:327)
>           at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.(ActorSystem.scala:650)
>           at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:244)
>           at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:287)
>           at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:262)
>           at play.core.server.DevServerStart$.$anonfun$mainDev$1(DevServerStart.sc
>   ala:213)
>           at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$$Lambda$7/634563942.apply(Unknown So
>   urce)
>           at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
>           at play.core.server.DevServerStart$.mainDev(DevServerStart.scala:59)
>           at play.core.server.DevServerStart$.mainDevHttpMode(DevServerStart.scala
>   :49)
>           at play.core.server.DevServerStart.mainDevHttpMode(DevServerStart.scala)
>
> ```
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
> ```
>
> java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
>   sorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>           at play.runsupport.Reloader$.startDevMode(Reloader.scala:230)
>           at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun
>   $apply$3.devModeServer$lzycompute$1(PlayRun.scala:77)
>           at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun
>   $apply$3.play$sbt$run$PlayRun$$anonfun$$anonfun$$anonfun$$devModeServer$1(PlayRu
>   n.scala:77)
>           at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun
>   $apply$3.apply(PlayRun.scala:100)
>           at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun
>   $apply$3.apply(PlayRun.scala:63)
>           at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47) [trace]
>   Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
>   [error] (compile:run) java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   [error] Total time: 1 s, completed 2017-09-02 12:47:18
>   [play-scala-starter-example] $

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: older JDK version (1.8.0_101) not matching newer Scala version (2.12.2). Error disappeared after update to jdk1.8.0_144

Same as here:

[Scala build crashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628310/scala-build-crashed)

Comment: Even for 2.11, JDK < 1.8 is not supported for Play >= 2.4

Comment: As you can see, my JDK was 1.8 all along. It's the specific update that is required - which is not specified in the docs